# Android Device doesn't appear online in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-11.10

I just updated my ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 and getting this problem, my android device does not appear online while I run android project from eclipse.I've attached a screenshot. I also put file in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

the content of 51-android.rules file is
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

screenshot is
[image: device not appear online, it just show unknown]

Comment: check for your eclipse version and compatibility of your android plugin. If you have installed your eclipse version from packet manager then it will not support android plugin.

Comment: it was perfect work before I update ubuntu , after I update ubuntu 12.04 it not working, (I update ubuntu not reinstall new version of ubuntu, so my eclipse, it plugin and all software as it is).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SYSFS was deprecated in the recent versions of udev.

Your file should only have lines like this:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

where 0bb4 is the vendor id.

You can get the vendor id for your phone through the terminal. Run 'lsusb' on the commmand line and find the line with your device.

For example, on my case:
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 18d1:4e22 Google Inc. Nexus S (debug)

So the vender id is 18d1.

And the above line becomes:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Comment: Good stuff! I used this on my Nexus 4, though the manufacturer was LG the vender id was googles... Should be fixed in their official guide tbh: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html, that nexus terminals aren't using their manufacturers vender id!